# Value range of parameter inequality.

Tags: inequality

Assume $a,b,c>0$ satisfies :$$5c-3a \leq b \leq 4c-a$$ and $$c\ln b \geq a + c\ln c$$. Find the value range of $\frac{b}{a}$.

---

My approach:

because $a>0$ and I want to construct the target expression : $\frac{b}{a}$. I divide the first inequality by $a$ in the three part. and I get : $$5\frac{c}{a}-3 \leq \frac{b}{a} \leq 4 \frac{c}{a} - 1$$. In the second inequality. I also want to construct the $\frac{b}{a}$. $$c\ln b -c \ln a \geq a+c\ln c -c \ln a \Rightarrow \frac{b}{a} \geq \frac{c}{a} \exp{\frac{a}{c}}$$

But I can't go any further. It is depressed me a lot ..  What is the right way to solve this ? I don't know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B = \frac{b}a, \: C = \frac{c}a$.  Note that we need the range of $B$.  Then you have already obtained the following two inequalities in terms of these variables:
$$5C - 3 \le B \le 4C-1, \qquad B \ge Ce^{1/C}$$

The first inequality needs $5C-3 \le 4C-1 \implies C \le 2$.  Further $B > 0 \implies 4C-1 > 0 \implies C > \frac14$.  Thus $C$ can take only values in $(\frac14, 2]$.  Correspondingly, $B$ has to be in $(0, 7]$.

The second inequality further requires that we must have $\displaystyle B \ge \min_C Ce^{1/C}=  e$.  So it seems $B \in [e, 7]$ is the range.

Answer (score 1):

Here what I did:

We have the following inequality:

$$5c-3a\leq b\leq 4c-a.\quad\quad (E_0)$$

Since $b>0$, then I can divide by $b$:

$$\dfrac{5c-3a}{b}\leq 1\leq \dfrac{4c-a}{b}.\quad (1)$$

Further $(1)$ can be seen as:

$$\dfrac{5c-3a}{b}\leq 1\leq \dfrac{5c-3a+2a-c}{b},$$
or
$$\dfrac{5c-3a}{b}\leq 1\leq \dfrac{5c-3a}{b}+\dfrac{2a-c}{b},$$
or
$$0\leq 1-\dfrac{5c-3a}{b}\leq \dfrac{2a-c}{b}.\quad (2)$$

With $(2)$ we can conclude that: $\dfrac{2a-c}{b}\geq0$ and since $b>0$ then $2a-c\geq0$.

Finally we have: $$\dfrac{c}{a}\leq2.\quad\quad (E_1)$$

Now, back to $(E_0)$ and divide it by $a$, we get:

$$5\dfrac{c}{a}-3\leq \dfrac{b}{a}\leq 4\dfrac{c}{a}-1.\quad (3)$$

Using $(E_1)$, we have an upper bound:
$$\dfrac{b}{a}\leq 4\dfrac{c}{a}-1\leq7.$$

Now, it time to use the logarithm inequality to get the lower bound.

We have:

$$c\log b\geq a+c\log c.$$

First divide it by $c$, we get:

$$\log b\geq \dfrac{a}{c}+\log c.$$

Again we use $(E_1)$ to see that: $\log \dfrac{b}{c}\geq \dfrac{a}{c} \geq\dfrac{1}{2}>0.$ (I needed this to guarantee that $\log \dfrac{b}{c}>0$). Then, this is useful to divide by $\log \dfrac{b}{c}$ in both sides. Then,

$$\dfrac{c}{a}\geq\dfrac{1}{\log \dfrac{b}{c}}.$$

Back to $(3)$ and use the left hand side, we get:

$$-3+5\dfrac{c}{a}\geq -3+\dfrac{5}{\log \dfrac{b}{c}}.\quad (4)$$

Now divide $(E_0)$ by $c$ and apply log (we about the right hand side) you get:

$$\log \dfrac{b}{c}\leq \log(4-\dfrac{a}{c}).$$

Which is equivalent to (using $(E_1)$)

$$\log \dfrac{b}{c}\leq \log(4-\dfrac{a}{c})\leq \log\dfrac{7}{2}.$$

Now use $(4)$ to get:

$$-3+5\dfrac{c}{a}\geq -3+\dfrac{5}{\log \dfrac{b}{c}}\geq -3+\dfrac{5}{\log \dfrac{7}{2}}.\quad (E_2)$$

Conclusion:

$$-3+\dfrac{5}{\log \dfrac{7}{2}}\leq \dfrac{b}{a}\leq 7.$$
$$0.99\leq \dfrac{b}{a}\leq 7.$$

Edit: $\log$ is the natural logarithm. I calculated wrong before.

Comment: $(a, b, c) = (1, e, 1)$ seems to satisfy the original inequalities, which means $\frac{b}a = e$ is valid.  However this is not in your interval.

Comment: What is my wrong step?

Comment: Not able to follow your steps - have tried to explain separately, will look at your steps once again...

Comment: Where did you get $6.19$ from?  It is nowhere near $-3+\dfrac{5}{\log 3.5}$...

Comment: Yes I used log in google but not ln. I edit my answer. My steps look fine to me. Now it is correct Thanks :)